# Expand variables after filtering them out

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a lot of variables, some of these end with `_OBJDIR`. Now I want a single variable which contains the expansion of all the `_OBJDIR`. I know I can get halfway:

`ALLOBJDIRS = $(filter %_OBJDIR,$(.VARIABLES))`

But now I have:

`ALLOBJDIRS = A_OBJDIR B_OBJDIR C_OBJDIR`

And I want:

`ALLOBJDIRS = a/obj b/obj c/obj`

Where

`A_OBJDIR = a/obj`

Etcetera. How can I expand ALLOBJDIRS after the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining 'foreach' with 'value' function to expand variable values

```
@echo ALLOBJDIR = $(foreach v, $(filter %_OBJDIR,$(.VARIABLES)), $(value $v))
```

Also, the ${${VAR}} can be used,

```
@echo ALLOBJDIR = $(foreach v, $(filter %_OBJDIR,$(.VARIABLES)), ${${v}})
```